# Best way to organize sizes/colors with products in database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am creating an online store for apparell and stuck on finding a good way to create various sizes and colors for my products, currently I create a product with the information below:

```
app.post("/products", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.body;
    const { category } = req.body;
    const { price } = req.body;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const { image } = req.body;
    const newProduct = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO products(name, category, price, description, image) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *",
      [name, category, price, description, image]
    );
    res.json(newProduct.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

but also need a way to tell if the user selects a different size as well as a different color, so my current setup in my database is three tables, which are:
1.) Products(As above)
2.) Colors
3.) Sizes
This is what they look like in pgAdmin4
[image]

How do i make it for when i create one new shirt using that post request that 4 other sizes are linked to it as well as a couple colors? Should i implement it in the code above or is there a better way about going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of an "IKEA" furniture, you have

- Furniture type ("STOCKHOLM couch 3 person")
- some color variations ("red, green")
- some fabric variations ("leather, cotton")

Each unique combination has a UID, the 8-digit part number.

So my example db could be something along

```
123-000-01 | STOCKHOLM  | RD | LE
123-000-02 | STOCKHOLM  | GN | LE
123-000-03 | STOCKHOLM  | RD | CT
123-000-04 | STOCKHOLM  | GN | CT
```

Now when people select that type I can present various colors and types.

I can' see that linking tables by product_id to different colors would work, since same product_id can't be different colors at same time ? Perhaps do it by product type ID instead ? Or use just one table.

This is how I would do it.

Comment: I dont know if this will exactly work, since i dont want to display all different sizes and shirts on my homepage when i map out the database, but only want to display but one shirt and then from there they can select different sizes or colors, what would you recommend to solve that?